# numpy Finding multiple occurrence in an array by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

Given the following array:

```
array = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 3, -1, 3, -1, -1,  2,  2, -1, -1,  1, -1]
 indexes  0   1   2   3   4   5  6  7   8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
```

I need to find the indexes where the same number appears.
In this example this would return a list of lists like this:

```
list(list(), list(16), list(12, 13), list(6, 7, 9), list() etc...)
     0       1     \   2             3              4
     ^              \ 
      \              \ the index in the array at which "1" appears
       \ 
        \ the numbers in the array
```

how would one do this in numpy?

the number 1 appears at index 16
the number 2 appears at indexes 12, 13
etc.

NOTES based on comments:

- -1 can be ignored, i'm only interested in the rest
- array has ~50 elements with values up to int(500)
- this function will be called 6000+ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a solution in `O(n)` time*, use a dictionary to collect the indices:

```
# collect positions per value for each item
d = {}
for i, x in enumerate(array):
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(i)

# sort the output (optional)
out = {k: d[k] for k in sorted(d)}
```

Output:

```
{-1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17],
  1: [16],
  2: [12, 13],
  3: [6, 7, 9]}
```

* + `O(k*log(k))` where `k` is the number of unique values if you need a sorted output

For a list of lists:

```
out = [d.get(k, []) for k in range(min(d), max(d)+1)]

# or for only positive values
out = [d.get(k, []) for k in range(1, max(d)+1)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17],
 [],
 [16],
 [12, 13],
 [6, 7, 9]]
```

##### alternative

Or a very simple approach if you pre initialize the output:

```
out = [[] for i in range(max(array)+1)]
for i, x in enumerate(array):
    out[x].append(i)
```

##### comparison of all approaches

pure python is the fastest here.

The initial array was generated using `np.random.randint(0, k, size=n).tolist()` where `n` is the length of the array and `k` the maximum value in the array.

With `k=4`:

[image]

With `k=100`:

*We can now see the quadratic behavior of @TalhaTayyab/@Stitt/@PaulS approaches.*

[image]

With `k=10_000`:

*We can note that numpy is a bit faster for relatively small arrays (when the values are likely unique).*

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you for your time and for the comparison analysis.

Comment: @AndreiM. you're welcome, I updated the timings for Stitt's code to perform only once the conversion to array (although I didn't convert the output to lists, so that would make it a bit slower)

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 3, -1, 3, -1, -1,  2,  2, -1, -1,  1, -1]
s = sorted(set(array))
print(s)  # all the unique elements in the list

#output
[-1, 1, 2, 3] 

[([i for i,d in enumerate(array) if d == x],x) for x in s]

#output
[([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17], -1),   #[([indices],element)]
 ([16], 1),
 ([12, 13], 2),
 ([6, 7, 9], 3)]
```

Comment: The solution is however of quadratic complexity, this will become quite slow if you have many different values

Comment: yes i did not think it was worth mentioning but in the array there can be up to 500 values

also this function needs to be re-called about 6000+ times.

Answer (score 1):

@talha-tayyab's answer will work if you only need to consider the values that *do* appear in the array, however, if you need to start from `value=0` and increment up to the highest value, this should work.

```
array = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 3, -1, 3, -1, -1,  2,  2, -1, -1,  1, -1]
max = numpy.max(array)

result = []
for i in range(max):
    result.append(numpy.argwhere(array == i))

return result
```

Comment: Like in the other answer, the complexity is quadratic. You shouldn't need to loop over the array more than once. Also, you might not have tested the code but it contains syntax errors and doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: Note that you need to have `array = np.array(array)` for the code to work

Answer (score 1):

A numpy solution:

```py
l1 = np.array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 3, -1, 3, -1, -1,  2,  2, -1, -1,  1, -1])

unique, counts = np.unique(l1, return_counts=True)
print(dict(zip(unique, np.split(np.argsort(l1), np.cumsum(counts)))))
```

Prints:

```
{
    -1: array([0, 15, 14, 11, 10, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 17]),
    1: array([16]),
    2: array([12, 13]),
    3: array([6, 7, 9]),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `itertools.groupby` + `operator.itemgetter` approach:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[[k, list(i[0] for i in g)] for k, g in groupby(sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1))]
```

---

```
[[-1, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17]],
 [1, [16]],
 [2, [12, 13]],
 [3, [6, 7, 9]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
[(x, np.where(array == x)[0].tolist()) for x in np.unique(array)]
```

Output:

```
[(-1, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17]),
 (1, [16]),
 (2, [12, 13]),
 (3, [6, 7, 9])]
```

Comment: I just saw your answer, I didn't run all test again, but it's also quadratic [with `k=100`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7eo5.png) ;)